# react native xcode project not build on iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, ios12

After updating ios to the 12th version and updating xcode to the latest version, I can't build the project.

I was able to successfully build the project in xcode, but when I build on iPhone I get the following verdict:

```
window.addEventListener is not a function. 
(In 'window.addEventListener('message', 
idleTick, false)', 'window.addEventListener' is 
undefined)

<unknown>
schedule.development.js:366.26

<unknown>
schedule.development.js:15.2

loadModuleImplementation
require.js:213:12

<unknown>
index.js:6:19

<unknown>
react-dom.development.js:21:15

<unknown>
react-dom.development.js:15:2

loadModuleImplementation
require.js:213:12

<unknown>
index.js:37:19

loadModuleImplementation
require.js:213:12

<unknown>
index.js:5

loadModuleImplementation
require.js:213:12

guardedLoadModule
require.js:140:45

global core
<unknown file>:0
```

What can I do to build the project? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That looks like react, not react native.

Comment: This is react native ios application that is built using xcode